# Sorting using Ack Grep Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sorting

I have this file in format:

```
ID:10Time:[12:55:28.156452]
ID:11Time:[12:55:28.156542]
ID:12Time:[12:55:28.157418]
ID:13Time:[12:55:28.157446]
ID:14Time:[12:55:28.167463]
ID:15Time:[12:55:28.167490]
ID:16Time:[12:55:28.176210]
```

I would like to sort this file based on the Time Stamp value in braces.
I am a beginner in this, I think this will give me a start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sort logfile by timestamp on linux command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347054/sort-logfile-by-timestamp-on-linux-command-line)

Comment: You've tagged this with C++. Do you need a solution in C++ or is any Linux solution okay?

Comment: No. Only in awk Grep, thanks the Problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

use sort with -kn flag

```
sort -k2 file
```

Comment: No, It does not do anything. I would like to sort the row as well based on the timestamps.

Comment: @Hiesenberg, what output format do you want? give me an example?

Comment: ID:12Time:[12:55:28.157418] ID:11Time:[12:55:28.156542], row which has least timestamp should come first.

Comment: timestamp of ID 12 is 157418, larger than 156542, which timestamp of ID 11. You want reverse sort? use -r flag:  "sort -k2 -r file"

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the file with the [`sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) utility:

```
sort -t'[' -k2 infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

You can sort the lines according to one or several keys which you specify with `-k` or `--key`. The value refers to columns numbers, starting with 1. Usually, the columns are separated by white space, but with `-t` you can specify a custom field separator.

Answer (score 0):

`sort -t':' -k3 inputfile`

`-t` specifies field seperator, and `-k3` means that lines will be sorted upon a key consisting of fields from the third one to the last