# Parse Cloudwatch Log Already Exported to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I exported my Cloudwatch logs to S3 using the process found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasks.html

Now I have a huge number of smaller Cloudwatch log files in S3. Is there a tool I can use to parse them/search them all in one go? I'm thinking of something like the [awslogs](https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs) tool used for downloading them from Cloudwatch, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to grep through the logfiles manually, and found a way to do this:

- Download the logfiles recursively from S3 to the local dir:

`aws s3 cp --recursive s3://<bucket name>/<bucket subdir>/ ./`

- Different streams in my Cloudwatch log group are from different applications with different timestamp formats, so grep out the one I want recursively using `zgrep -r`.
- My logfile line looks like this:

`api-api-0f73ed57-e0fc-4e69-a932-4ee16e28a9e6/000002.gz:2017-02-02T22:48:49.135Z [2017-02-02 22:48:49] Main.DEBUG: Router threshold 99.97 [] {"ip":"10.120.4.27"}`

- So use `sort -sk<key 1>,<key 2>` to sort on the second and third whitespace-separated fields (`[2017-02-02` and `22:48:49]`)
- This gives me the following command:

`zgrep -r api-api logfile* | grep "Main.DEBUG" | sort -sk2,3`

Thanks to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347054/sort-logfile-by-timestamp-on-linux-command-line) for the tips on `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as they are in S3 you can't do much with them. You might be able to use [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-athena-interactive-sql-queries-for-data-in-amazon-s3/) to query them, but I'm not sure they would be in the correct format.

You could spin up an [Elastic MapReduce](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/) cluster to parse the log files. You could run queries through EMR, or possibly use EMR to insert the data into [Elasticsearch](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) or [Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/) where you could then query the data.

If you just want to do [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) style searches through these files you will need to first download all the files so that they are local to the machine where you are running the `grep` tool.

Comment: Thanks. Someone's suggested downloading them and then going through them recursively with ```less``` or with ```zgrep | less``` - they turn up as a large number of stream directories with individual .gz files in them. But then I'd still have the challenge of how to order them by timestamp.