# Sort lines by timestamp in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I have a log file which is written by several threads and therefore not in order. 
The log contains entries like this:

```
[2018-07-11 15:30:39.139] [ddm.iolib.InputWorker] [debug] pop cmd from in queue...

[2018-07-11 15:30:39.140] [ddm.iolib.InputWorker] [debug] push cmd to out queue...
```

I would like to sort the lines by time stamp.
I found this great answers for sorting in bash: [sort logfile by timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347054/sort-logfile-by-timestamp-on-linux-command-line)

This works fine, but I would like to sort this in Emacs. I tried using sort-regexp-fields, but it seems I am not clever enough to get it to work.
What I tried is:

```
^.*\([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\]\).*$
```

as records specifier and \1 as key. Nothing at all was sorted.
Could please someone tell me, what am I doing wrong?
I am also open for other possibilities than sort-regexp-fields.

@Toby Speight Thanks for the hint. I understand the problem and will try to avoid such questions in future. I am just debugging a lot with logging and this sorting will be very helpful for me in a lot of future cases. I am new to SO, so please accept my apologize.

@Picaud Vincent I would upvote if I could. Never used shell-command-on-region. Actually sort-lines was sufficient for this case, but your approach will be useful in the future, so your answer is accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the time stamp is always first in the line, does `M-x sort-lines` do what you want? (Type `C-x h` first, to select the entire buffer)

Comment: A standard `sort-lines` call should be adequate - that's the great advantage of using ISO-8601 timestamps!

Comment: Questions about *using* programs such as Emacs are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they are specific to programming modes; you may be able to get help on [emacs.se] or [su].  If your question is about programming Emacs, then please [edit] to include a [mcve] of the Lisp or C code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply any bash command to a selected region:

Please follow these steps:

1. select your region (or the whole buffer with `C-x h`)
2. type `C-u M-|`, Emacs will prompt you for your shell command, enter `sort -k1 -r` for instance

And that's it! (attention, it is `M-|` and not `M-!`)

Extract from Emacs doc (you can get it with `C-h k M-|`):

> M-| runs the command shell-command-on-region (found in global-map),
>   which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.
>
> It is bound to M-|,   .
>
> (shell-command-on-region START END COMMAND &optional OUTPUT-BUFFER
>
> REPLACE ERROR-BUFFER DISPLAY-ERROR-BUFFER REGION-NONCONTIGUOUS-P)
>
> Execute string COMMAND in inferior shell with region as input.
>   Normally display output (if any) in temp buffer ‘*Shell Command
>   Output*’; Prefix arg means replace the region with it.  Return the
>   exit code of COMMAND.

In other terms `M-|` runs the shell command and displays output in the ‘Shell Command Output’ buffer. If you want this output to replace the selected region you must prefix the `M-|` command, this is our `C-u` command (step 2).

---

Answering to @Toby Speight comment here is an example. I use as initial buffer these lines (your [question provided link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7347054/2001017))

```
freeswitch.log:2011-09-08 12:21:07.282236 [ERR] ftdm_queue.c:136 Failed to enqueue obj 0x7f2cda3525c0 in queue 0x7f2ce8005990, no more room! windex == rindex == 58!
freeswitch.log:2011-08-08 13:21:07.514261 [ERR] ftdm_queue.c:136 Failed to enqueue obj 0x7f2cda354460 in queue 0x7f2ce8005990, no more room! windex == rindex == 58!
freeswitch.log:2011-06-04 16:21:08.998227 [ERR] ftdm_queue.c:136 Failed to enqueue obj 0x7f2cda356300 in queue 0x7f2ce8005990, no more room! windex == rindex == 58! 
freeswitch.log:2011-09-08 12:21:10.374238 [ERR] ftdm_queue.c:136 Failed to enqueue obj 0x7f2cda3581a0 in queue 0x7f2ce8005990, no more room! windex == rindex == 58!
```

I type: `C-x h C-u M-| sort -k1 -r <RET>` (where `<RET>` stands for the "return" keyboard key) as result my buffer contains now:

```
freeswitch.log:2011-09-08 12:21:10.374238 [ERR] ftdm_queue.c:136 Failed to enqueue obj 0x7f2cda3581a0 in queue 0x7f2ce8005990, no more room! windex == rindex == 58!
freeswitch.log:2011-09-08 12:21:07.282236 [ERR] ftdm_queue.c:136 Failed to enqueue obj 0x7f2cda3525c0 in queue 0x7f2ce8005990, no more room! windex == rindex == 58!
freeswitch.log:2011-08-08 13:21:07.514261 [ERR] ftdm_queue.c:136 Failed to enqueue obj 0x7f2cda354460 in queue 0x7f2ce8005990, no more room! windex == rindex == 58!
freeswitch.log:2011-06-04 16:21:08.998227 [ERR] ftdm_queue.c:136 Failed to enqueue obj 0x7f2cda356300 in queue 0x7f2ce8005990, no more room! windex == rindex == 58!
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for the feedback. however I m not sure to understand well your request: there is no code as the solution is simply to type C-x h C-u M-| sort -k1 -r <RET> under Emacs. We could have defined an Emacs-lisp function for that but this is certainly an overkill solution. For better clarity, I have added a complete usage example.

Comment: As it is, a series of interactive keystrokes is really a [su] or [emacs.se] answer, rather than a [so] one.  It may of course be that the question is on the wrong site - I've commented accordingly.

Comment: @TobySpeight I will try to avoid such kind of question/answer in the future. I do understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Even though Picaud Vincent's answer describes an important method for emacs users to have in their toolbelt, I want to record for posterity the answer from the comments, since it is simple and solves the OP's problem exacly with a minimum of fuss:

- Mark the appropriate region (perhaps with `C-x h` to mark the whole buffer).
- `M-x sort-lines`

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `sort-regexp-fields`, but given that the timestamp is at the beginning of the line (and your use of ISO 8601 format for the timestamp), that means that they can be sorted quite simply with `sort-lines`.  Assuming you want to sort the whole buffer, that's just

```
(sort-lines nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

The approach you had would match only the *time* part of the timestamp, so you could end up with different days intermingled.